# Copy and pasting .so file doesn't work with linker

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, dynamic-library, casablanca

I compiled and built the casablanca c++ rest library in my home directory where my absolute path to the necessary .so file was `/home/dev/casablanca/Release/build.release/Binaries/libcpprest.so`. What I wanted to do was to simply `cp` and past that .so file to `/usr/lib/..` path to default lib search `../` so that I could easily link it with the following command:

```
g++ index.cpp -I/home/dev/casablanca/Release/include -lcpprest -std=c++11
```

which compiled fine, but when I ran ./a.out I got the typical runtime error:

```
couldn't load shared library: libcpprest.so
```

even after adding the default path of libcpprest.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

However everything worked just fine if I linked the directory where the binary was originally created at:

```
// ./a.out runs just fine
g++ index.cpp -I/home/dev/casablanca/Release/include \
   -L/home/dev/casablanca/Release/build.release/Binaries -lcpprest -std=c++11
```

I'm guessing that the reason why I can't simply move the .so object where I want to add it is somehow the compiler keeps references to it somehow. How can I install this binary in a different path?

Comment: `a.out` that "runs just fine should not be running at all because `-L` does not set any path to search at runtime. You are probably not telling the whole story. Use `ldd` on your executable and libraries and make sure the environment is identical in all cases. Also, what's this `usr/lib/..`? Are you running as root and dumping everything to `/usr`?

Comment: I think the issue might be that there's a bunch of .o files that the .so is linking against. If the .so changes directories it may break those links. That's my guess.

Comment: "If the .so changes directories it may break those links.". Only if you instruct the linker to make it so, which you didn't. Have you used `ldd` on your executables and libraries? Is there anything suspicious in the output?

Comment: eh I give up, I just had to modify the cmake file to through my lib in /usr/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did compile casablanca on my linux debian ( https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca ) with procedure https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20Linux&referringTitle=Documentation

after compilation i get a libcpprest.so with that (objdump) :

SONAME               libcpprest.so.2.2

so you might want to copy libcpprest.so.2.2 to /usr/lib/libcpprest.so.2.2

or use ldconfig tool to do so.

looking into Release/build.release/Binaries you will find :

```
libcpprest.so -> libcpprest.so.2.2
libcpprest.so.2.2
```

then **libcpprest.so is just a link**, real library is libcpprest.so.2.2

Comment: I think you also have to build a symlink libcpprest.so -> libcpprest.so.2.2

Comment: i did that very quickly this morning and had to leave before completing. i updated my answer. Since it is a relative link copying it is not enough, you have to copy source link too.

Answer (score 1):

The section you are referring to is tuned by the [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) switch:

g++ -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib ...